# Preventing array index crash by checking array count, is there any performance issue ?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

For avoiding crash issue, if I check the array count before accessing every index like the following code then is there any performance issue? Is it a good practice or bad practice for big apps ?

My Code is:

```
-(BOOL)checkIndexAvailability:(NSArray *)array_ withIndex:(int)index_
{
    if ((array_.count-1)>=index_) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

When I access any array I call like this:

```
if ([self checkIndexAvailability:regDataArray withIndex:2]) {
    lastName = [regDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling method and get BOOL value, you can directly check with count value. It's better than method call.

Comment: Or even hold a variable with your array's length and check against it (instead of hitting the array every time)

Comment: A straight forward check of index < [array count] would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks all, specially Alladinian. :-)

Comment: Why don't you use if(2 < [regDataArray count]) lastName = [regDataArray objectAtIndex:2]; directly?

Comment: I did it directly before, but If I code like this, what will be the performance issue. I can understand now from Alladinian's answer, I don't need to access the array again and again. As the array_.count will execute the count method. 

And I can directly check also.

int arrayCount = [regDataArray count];
if (2<arrayCount) {
        firstName = [regDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
}

Comment: Use `YES` and `NO` in obj-c, not `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Alladanian, brainLikeApple and Kris Gellic's answer, I understand that preventing the Array Index out of bounds crash issue can be solved by following this way:

```
int arrayCount = [regDataArray count];

NSString *lastName = ( 2 <arrayCount) ? [regDataArray objectAtIndex:2] : @"Last Name Not Found";
NSString *address = ( 4< arrayCount) ? [regDataArray objectAtIndex:4] : @"No Address Found";
```

There don't need to create another method or accessing array count method every time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just doing a quick inline check to make it a little bit better.  Something like this:

```
lastName = (regDataArray.count - 1 > 2) ? [regDataArray objectAtIndex:2] : nil;
```

Although you wont notice any speed with difference with your way or mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that doing that way should not delay your app that much.

But take in account that when your're programming, if things are done the right way your programm should never try to get something of an array position that does not exist.

You can find some more information [Bounds checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be encapsulated in category. Or maybe, you can change standard implementation using runtime library.
Also it will be great if you add something like assertion in debug mode, so you don't hide issues in implementation which send wrong indexes.
P.S. I don't think it can dramatically affect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reason to add checks like this because `NSArray` already does similar checks. It raises an exception when the `index` is invalid.

Now, maybe you are asking why I think that raising an exception is better then silently skipping `objectAtIndex`. Well, if you are trying to index something that's not there, it's a bug. Silently skipping the code only hides the bug from you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I working with an unknown array that is generated from OCR. So depending on the image capturing the might be different. If the array index isn't there then I can also notify it, and its better than crashing.

Comment: Then a normal check `i < array.count` would be more appropiate or possibly a `for` iteration over the array.